# Apply a continuous animation to a Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, canvas

I want to apply a continuous **FadeIn/FadeOut** animation to a specific `Canvas` in my `WPF`.

I'm able to do the **`FadeOut`** part but then the **`FadeIn`** part executes immediately after that and ruins the animation.

I also want all of this to be in a smooth loop without interfering with my normal operations.

*Look at it as an animated background.*

What's the best method to do this? Should I use `While`? or should I use `Timer`? ...

```
var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
var fadeOut = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, duration);
var fadeIn = new DoubleAnimation(1.0, duration);
MyCanvas.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fadeOut);
MyCanvas.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fadeIn);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `AutoReverse` and `RepeatBehavior` properties of a single DoubleAnimation to get a continous effect:

```
var fadeInOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = 0,
    To = 1,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    AutoReverse = true,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
};

MyCanvas.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fadeInOutAnimation);
```

---

In your approach you would have to set the `BeginTime` property of the second animation to the `Duration` of the first one.

Comment: Can it pause for like 1 second before repeating again?

Comment: I guess not, but you may play around with easing functions like `EasingFunction = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn }` and perhaps a duration of 2 seconds.